# PostgreSQL - Identify if an update is from a trigger or a user

Tags: postgresql, triggers

In `PostgreSQL 13.2` I have a table with 5 fields : id, val1, val2, val3, update_origin.

Step 1 : A trigger generate 'val3' when 'val1' or 'val2' are created or updated. This trigger also update the field 'update_origin' with a 'trigger update' value.

Step 2 : An user can also directly create or update val3, and if so I create a trigger who update the field 'update_origin' with a 'user update' value.

With this settings there are no differences between an automatic trigger update and a manual user update because nothing identify the source of the update (second step is always true, for `PostgreSQL` an update is an update).

How to make a difference between an update from a trigger (example of step 1) or from an user (example of step 2) ?

**Sequence**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE demo_id_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    START 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 2147483647
    CACHE 1;
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE demo
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('demo_id_seq'::regclass),    
    val1 character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    val2 character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    val3 character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    update_origin character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

**Function #1**

```
CREATE FUNCTION val3_concat()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE demo
    SET val3 = CONCAT(val1, ' ', val2),
    update_origin = 'trigger update'
    WHERE id = currval('demo_id_seq');
RETURN null;  
END
$BODY$;
```

**Trigger #1**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_val3_concat
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF val1, val2
    ON demo
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE val3_concat();
```

**Function #2**

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_origin()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    IF OLD.val3 <> NEW.val3 THEN
        UPDATE demo
        SET update_origin = 'user update'
        WHERE id = currval('demo_id_seq');
    END IF;
RETURN NEW; 
END
$BODY$;
```

**Trigger #2**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_origin
    AFTER UPDATE OF val3
    ON demo
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_origin();
```

An example with `INSERT INTO demo (val1, val2) VALUES ('first', 'shot');` table will return `1, first, shot, first shot, trigger update`.

If I update 'val1' or val2' table will return `1, first, shot, first shot, user update` or I expected to be this only if i update 'val3' and only 'val3'.

Comment: There is no need to use UPDATE in the trigger. Use a `BEFORE` trigger and _assign_ the value you want: `new.update_origin := 'trigger update';`

Comment: Perhaps there is an answer if we know *why* you need to be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Make the functions `BEFORE UPDATE` and test the value of `val3`.  If  the `OLD.val3 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.val3` then the user changed it before it got to the function. Based on that set the `update_origin` to `user_update`. Otherwise let the function generate `val3` and set `update_origin` to `trigger_update`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe my context : I need to know if 'val3' is generated by the trigger when 'val1' or 'val2' are created or updated or if an user have manually create or update 'val3'. It's for traceability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE demo
(
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,    
    val1 varchar,
    val2 varchar,
    val3 varchar,
    update_origin varchar
)
;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_origin()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        IF OLD.val3 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.val3 THEN
            NEW.update_origin = 'user update';
        ELSE
            NEW.val3 = NEW.val1 || ' ' || NEW.val2;
            NEW.update_origin = 'trigger update';
        END IF;
    ELSEIF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        IF NEW.val3 IS NOT NULL THEN
            NEW.update_origin = 'user update';
        ELSE
            NEW.val3 = NEW.val1 || ' ' || NEW.val2;
            NEW.update_origin = 'trigger update';
        END IF;
    END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END
$function$
;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_origin
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON demo
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_origin();

insert into demo (val1, val2) values ('1', '2'); 
INSERT 0 1
test_(aklaver)(5432)=> select * from demo;
 id | val1 | val2 | val3 | update_origin  
----+------+------+------+----------------
  2 | 1    | 2    | 1 2  | trigger update
insert into demo (val1, val2, val3) values ('3', '4', '5');
INSERT 0 1
test_(aklaver)(5432)=> select * from demo;
 id | val1 | val2 | val3 | update_origin  
----+------+------+------+----------------
  2 | 1    | 2    | 1 2  | trigger update
  3 | 3    | 4    | 5    | user update
update demo set val1 = '6' where id = 2;
UPDATE 1
test_(aklaver)(5432)=> insert into demo (val1, val2, val3) values ('3', '4', '5');
INSERT 0 1
test_(aklaver)(5432)=> select * from demo;
 id | val1 | val2 | val3 | update_origin  
----+------+------+------+----------------
  3 | 3    | 4    | 5    | user update
  2 | 6    | 2    | 6 2  | trigger update
  4 | 3    | 4    | 5    | user update
```

Roll both functions into one and use `TG_OP` to distinguish between operations.

Comment: Thanks for this detailled answer, behaviour is what I expected (and try to explain). I am not yet comfortable with triggers and before/after, old/new notions. For my personal knowledge is there a difference between `new.update_origin := 'trigger update';` and `new.update_origin = 'trigger update';` ? Apparently not.

Comment: No difference, see [assignment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT).